# Polymer Passing Properties To Child Elements In Firefox

Tags: polymer

I've created a simple example http://jsbin.com/yifekigo/21/edit. It works in Chrome and does not in Firefox/Safari. It will work in Firefox if I change `<nest-row mCols="{{mCols}}" y="{{y}}"></nest-row>` to `<nest-row mCols="4"  y="{{y}}"></nest-row>`.

How can I get Firefox and Safari to pass the value of mCols from nest-grid through to nest-row?

EDIT: See Scott's comment on his answer for the use of domReady as a workaround.

Comment: Can you simplify your code down so that it's as simple as possible while also having the problem you describe? That makes it far easier for others unfamiliar with your code and all of its moving pieces to track down what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, on Firefox/Safari/IE, the DRY Polymer syntax is not supported in the main document. IOW, you must do:

```
Polymer('nest-grid', {...
```

instead of

```
Polymer({...
```

Again, this is only true for calls like this in the main document (which typically includes JsBin and friends). Polymer elements in imports can use the DRY syntax on all platforms.

Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Adding 'nest-grid', 'nest-row' and 'nest-element' to the Polymer definitions does not make the provided example work. Also in my testing I use separate files for each polymer-element and both the DRY and WET(?) Polymer syntax does not work in browsers not Chrome. Would you be able to provide a modified version of my example which works in FF?

Comment: You may have uncovered a bug, I'll get back to you after some research. I was able to make it work by using `domReady` instead of `ready`, but that should not be necessary, or at least it should not vary between Chrome and other browsers. See here: http://jsbin.com/yifekigo/26/edit. Other notes: (1) only load one 'polymer', (2) declare your elements in dependency order.

Comment: Makes me proud to find bugs. I'll use domReady for now while I build my application. If you could update the main answer I'll mark it as correct. Also the multiple 'polymer' include was due to jsbin's "Add library" -> Polymer 0.3.0. Not sure why they injected it twice and I didn't even bother to double check what it added. Thanks for the quick responses to my questions. I feel as I continue I'll have more.